# how can i import member in civicrm Drupal

Tags: drupal

Hi, I have a csv file with all member information. I want to import this file in civicrm. Although i have seen an import option in the civicrm menu, that option is not working for me. I have many other fields which are not present in the import option.

How can i import a csv file in civicrm?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to start is by exporting into a csv and then you can see what the Primary fields are. Do a search then select a contact and on the 'Actions' dropdown box select 'Export Contacts'. A wizard will guide you. Select Primary Fields for you first attempt. Open the exported CSV file in Excel and see about 75 Primary fields. If you need something more you can add custom fields to CiviCRM.
When you want to import your own CSV you will need to map your fields to CiviCRM fields.
Try it on the CiviCRM demo site http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/